# How to change value aria-label in TypeScript/Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular7

I tried change value of `aria-label` in TypeScript/Angular 7, but when i build project i have an error

```
public changeAcessibility(isExpanded: boolean, id) {

    let aria = (<HTMLButtonElement>document.getElementById("aria_label_id_" + id));
    (document.getElementById('aria_label_id_' + id) as HTMLButtonElement).ariaLabel = "Changed Values"
    
  }
```

[image]

I tried too this code (the project build, but not change value of `aria-label`)

```
(document.getElementById('aria_label_id_' + id) as HTMLButtonElement).setAttribute('aria-label', 'Changed Values');
```

Comment: why (once using Angular) not using ie, attr binding: `<button id="arial_label_id_1" [attr.aria-labe;]="acessibilityVal"></button>`  ( in component `public changeAcess() { this.acessibilityVal = !!!this.acessibilityVal; } ` ... )

Comment: Something else is wrong with your code. Here's a working StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nmnuce?file=src/app/app.component.ts click the button to change the aria label.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e2i5k4?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: try using jquery,

Comment: @joyBlanks seriously? Where's the downvote comment button...

Comment: @joyBlanks really? if you use angular, why use jquery??

Comment: i inferred from the pattern of coding, and suggested relevant tech. use bindings subscribers if you are using angular. fallback to jquery or vanilla if using document model. Hope this clarifies

Comment: @Brandon: sorry bro didn't try to offend anyone.

Comment: @joyBlanks using jQuery in this context is just unnecessary and ill-advised. Why would we add an entire library just to select something by its ID?

Comment: I was encouraging him not to use Angular at all. If with Angular it should be used with a class variable. Toggle the class variable in the method and bind the `[attr.aria-label]="value?'before':'after'"`.